# Dynamically Generate Editable PDF

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, pdf-form, princexml

Is there a way to create an editable PDF programmatically?  By editable, I mean you can click in a text area and type in your name, that kind of thing.

I'm using Ruby and have found [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/samples/) and [Princely](http://github.com/mbleigh/princely) to be nice projects.  I'm wondering if they could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prince doesn't mention forms in the documentation, and renders forms as static drawings, so I doubt it.

pdfTeX can do it with the [hyperref](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) package. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/pdf-forms-tutorial/).

Example:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[backgroundcolor={1 1 0},value=can do forms]{hyperref}
\end{Form}
```

It looks like this:

> [screenshot http://grab.by/23nP](http://grab.by/23nP)

(Of course, then you're using TeX instead of whatever reports library you like. I'm sure there's an alternative.)